# Visual Studio 2013 without Debug windows control

Tags: visual-studio-2013

https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-BGO1Og_OSvU/VA6k-OwLF3I/AAAAAAAANjA/oJzDRdLFI6w/s1600/www.Aloxovn.com-control.png

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate Update 3.
But, it doesn't show all Debug features windows. Example: Debug\Windows\Locals or Disassembly tab.

Can you tell me how to show it?

Answer (score 0):

See the View Menu. View -> Output Window

Comment: In the output window(near the top) there is a drop down, where you can select the output type : Build, debug, buildorder...